# Class Counter init

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what template says:

```
def __init__(self):
    ## Initialize the instance variable that represents the count
```

And I wrote:

```
class Counter:
def __init_(self):
    self.__count = 0
def get_count(self):
    return self.__count
def increment(self):
    return self.__count == self.__count+ 1
def set_count(self, value):
    self.value = 0

import Counter
def main():
  # The following causes the constructor to be invoked:  __init__()
  score_counter = counter.Counter()  
  print(score_counter.get_count())   # Display the current value of counter
  for points in range(10):           # Increment the counter 10 times
    score_counter.increment()
  score_counter.set_count(100)       # Set counter to 100
  print(score_counter)               # Displays str representation of counter `
```

the 'count' should increment 0 to so on, but it stays 0 forever.

What do I have to write for `__init__` part?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to know what I am supposed to do for __init__(self) part.
It should not have anything else then self, but if I write self.__count = 0 , count stays 0 forever

Comment: You have comparison (==) in `increment` instead of assignment (=), `__init__` is okay

Comment: If i copy your code and paste it into a file, i am unable to run it which makes it hard for me to help. For example `import Counter` fails. `Counter`-class is not defined, `init`-function has a spelling error e.t.c. Fix this and people will have an easier time to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `increment`-function. It does not increment the `__count`-variable, instead it checks if `self.__count` is equal to `self.__count+ 1` and returns the answer (which is `True` or `False`)

To fix this, change

```
return self.__count == self.__count+ 1
```

to

```
self.__count = self.__count+ 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, clean implementation of what you are trying to do:

```
class foo:    

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def get_count(self):
        print(self.count)
        return self.count

    def increment_count(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1 


def main():

    # Create the object 
    f = foo()

    # Call the get_count function on the object
    f.get_count() # OUTPUT: 0

    # Increment the counter 
    f.increment_count()

    # Call the get_count function on the object 
    f.get_count()   # OUTPUT: 1


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Hope this helps